# Add prefix to the default namespace "xmlns"

Tags: java, dom

I am trying to add prefix to the default namespace of the DOM object, I was unable to achieve that, I have created a new node with no default Namesapce in it printed it to make sure no default namespace exists. Added an new attribute with a namespace with a prefix.

I was able to add the new attribute, but was not able to remove the default namespace. Can you tell me on how to achieve it.

```
for (int j = 0; j < ODMNode1.getAttributes().getLength(); j++) {
    System.out.println("Attribute: "
            + ODMNode1.getAttributes().item(j).getNodeName() + " = "
            + ODMNode1.getAttributes().item(j).getNodeValue());
    if (ODMNode1.getAttributes().item(j).getNodeName().equals("xmlns") &&
           ODMNode1.getAttributes().item(j).getNodeValue().equals("http://www.com.org"))'{
        System.out.println("Beforev Removed"+   ODMNode1.getAttributes().item(j).getNodeName());
        Element element = (Element) ODMNode1;
        element.removeAttribute("xmlns");
        System.out.println("Removed"+   element.getAttribute("xmlns"));
        System.out.println("After Removed"+ ODMNode1.getAttributes().item(j).getNodeName());
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see why you've used the "XPath" tag on this question so I am removing it.

Answer (score 0):

In the W3C DOM model, you can't change the namespace of a node. If you want a node with the same local name but a different namespace (including no namespace) then you have to create a new node. XSLT can help with that.

Comment: I have create a new node without default namespace  and printed all the attributes to make sure there is no attribute with default namespace, i dont see any default namespace in the output any how when i constructed the DOM object i see the default namespace back any ide............. ???????????//

Comment: You will need to edit your question and provide a code sample illustrating the problem. The namespace is a property of each node and if you have e.g. `<root xmlns="foo"><child><grandchild>...</grandchild></child></root>` as the markup parsed into a DOM document then all three element nodes are in the namespace and if you want to remove the namespace then you need to make sure you recreate each element in no namespace. XSLT can do that with `<xsl:template match="*"><xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace=""><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()/"></xsl:element></xsl:template>`.